# How to use REE in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-enterprise-edition

We would like to check to see if we run into issues with REE, what would be the process to switch between community rails and REE using RVM.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this is not a valid question.

Comment: Moderators just don't have the nerves to correct a question, but spend time closing it. what crap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the basics of rvm, documented on the [rvm site](https://rvm.io):

```
rvm install ree
rvm use ree
```